# How to deploy terraform configurations across aws organization

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a repo with multiple resource configurations(s3, vpc, glue, etc..) in terraform.

In my aws organization, there are multiple aws accounts like showed below

```
11111
22222
33333
44444
.
.
.
.
99999
```

I can able to deploy it to individual accounts by using `terraform.dev.tfvars, terraform.stage.tfvars, etc..`
But i want to deploy my terraform configurations through aws organization. so it will provision the resources to all aws accounts listed in the aws organization.

I am trying this approach but it seems a lot of configurations needs to create.

```
provider "aws" {
  alias = "11111"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "..."
  }
}

module "11111" {
  source = "./modules/per-account"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.11111
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "22222"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "..."
  }
}

module "22222" {
  source = "./modules/per-account"

  providers = {
    aws = aws.22222
  }
}
```

Can anyone provide any suggestions or help on this to achieve it.

Comment: Have you tried a loop in a script?

Comment: @lxop Is script required for this approach ? I have updated the question and I am pretty new to terraform can you please describe what to do

Comment: If each account has the exact same configuration, then it would probably be simplest to just do it with a script. If each account has a different set of resources configured, then you will naturally need to create a lot of separate configurations

Comment: I have one configuration which is same for all the account but variables need to change based on the accounts like subnet IDs, vpc ids, etc... How the script approach will be ? I mean like bash script, how we need to assume the role for each account and run terraform plan, apply . I need some insights, can you please explain a little bit more. Thank you for the response